# position_dodge2 with facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying create a function to generalized plotting interaction ratios. I just have a couple aesthetic questions.

If you look between the facets in the plot below, you'll notice that the columns for Pclass aren't aligned properly. How do you align them?

[image: too low rep :(]

I know that `position_dodge2(preserve = "single")` preserves the column width but not the position of the column, how do I change that?

Any other recommendations for the function?

This data is from the Titanic Kaggle dataset.

```
df <- structure(list(Pclass = structure(c(3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "factor"), Survived = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), Parch = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
x1 <- "Parch"
x2 <- "Pclass"
y <- "Survived"

x1 <- sym(x1)
x2 <- sym(x2)
y <- sym(y)
df %>%
    select(!!x1, !!x2, !!y) %>%
    group_by(!!x1, !!x2, !!y) %>%
    tally() %>%
    mutate(perc = n / sum(n)) %>%
    {
        if(sapply(select(df, !!x1), class) == "numeric") {
            ggplot(., aes(x = !!x1, y = perc, fill = !!x2))
        } else 
            ggplot(., aes(x = factor(!!x1), y = perc, fill = !!x2, group = !!x2))
    } +
    geom_col(position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single")) +
    facet_grid(vars(!!y)) +
    {
      if(sapply(select(df, !!x2), class) == "numeric") {
          scale_fill_gradient2(low = "blue", high = "red",
                         midpoint = 25)
      }
    } +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format(1)) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = 0:nrow(distinct(select(df, !!x1)))) +
    labs(x = x1, y = "Percentage") + theme_bw()
```

EDIT:

added code to make it reproducible.

Problem with replacing `position_dodge2` with `position_dodge` below

[image: rep too low :(]

Comment: some sample data from `df` would help... use `dput`

Comment: It sounds like you are after `position_dodge()` rather than `position_dodge2()`. This preserves the position of the columns if there is no data in one of the variables. I'm not sure if that is your exact problem as I can't reproduce your data - let me know if it makes any difference.

Comment: I've updated so it should be reproducible now, the problem I saw with `position_dodge` is that it doesn't leave the space empty if the column is missing.

Comment: Ah, you mean it puts the gap at the end rather than at the start/middle of each grouping? Hmmm. I think in that case you might need to make dummy data of 0s to replace where you have missing data.

Comment: Right, I want each column to be vertically aligned between the dependent variable, in this case `Survived`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is where `complete` from `tidyr` really helps by completing the missing cases with a specified value.  In this case, filling in the missing combinations with n = 0.  `position_dodge` is also the way to go, with `position_dodge2` being unnecessary.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'scales'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:purrr':
#> 
#>     discard
#> The following object is masked from 'package:readr':
#> 
#>     col_factor

df <- structure(list(Pclass = structure(c(3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "factor"), Survived = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), Parch = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
x1 <- "Parch"
x2 <- "Pclass"
y <- "Survived"

x1 <- sym(x1)
x2 <- sym(x2)
y <- sym(y)

df %>%
  select(!!x1, !!x2, !!y) %>%
  group_by(!!x1, !!x2, !!y) %>%
  tally() %>%
  complete(Pclass, Survived, fill = list(n = 0)) %>% 
  mutate(perc = n / sum(n)) %>%
  {
    if(sapply(select(df, !!x1), class) == "numeric") {
      ggplot(., aes(x = !!x1, y = perc, fill = !!x2))
    } else 
      ggplot(., aes(x = factor(!!x1), y = perc, fill = !!x2, group = !!x2))
  } +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge()) +
  facet_grid(vars(!!y)) +
  {
    if(sapply(select(df, !!x2), class) == "numeric") {
      scale_fill_gradient2(low = "blue", high = "red",
                           midpoint = 25)
    }
  } +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format(1)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 0:nrow(distinct(select(df, !!x1)))) +
  labs(x = x1, y = "Percentage") + theme_bw()
#> Warning: Removed 8 rows containing missing values (geom_col).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-01-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>